# How to give Tepig its tail? (Sculpting a curly tail)

Tags: sculpting

I'm sculpting Tepig in Blender but its tail is giving me headaches. Extending it with the grab tool doesn't seem to work very well as the tail is getting thinner at the end and it's getting more and more hard to deform it:
[image: Tail in sculpting mode]
[image]

Is there an elegant way to extend the tail more even?

Reference: https://www.pokewiki.de/Datei:Sugimori_498.png

[image: reference image]

Comment: Better ask "how to ..." or "ways to ..." do something rather than "what's the best way to ..." which makes the question opinion-based and attracts *close* votes.

Answer (score 4):

This methods seems to work fine!

1.create base tail using curve modifier !

[image]

2.Convert the curve to a mesh!

[image]

3.Add a iso-sphere and join it to curve mesh using boolean modifier.

[image]

[image]

4.now join the tail to the sculpt mesh using boolean modifier!

[image]

Now you have a tail and can add more detail to it with sculpting.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm less informed about sculpting but I think it's best to sculpt the tail as separate object using something like cylinder as base and then join it to your sculpt using bool tools.

you have a option of using dyntopo but it might not give perfect results.